# Function to automatically send email is not sending within specified thread

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a sheet with 2 columns (column A has message ID values and column B may or may not be blank). My function "sendEmail" will loop through these two columns and if column B has a value, then it should reply to a specific recipient in the thread with the message ID from column A (the recipient below is just example@example.com but I put my own email in my code). However, my function below is sending a brand new email and not responding within the thread. What could be going wrong?

```
function sendEmail () {
    const messageIDandRecordID = generator.getRange(2, 1, generator.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();

    messageIDandRecordID.forEach(function(row) {
        const messageId = row[0];
        const replyText = row[1];

        if (replyText) {
            const message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
            const replySubject = "Re: " + message.getSubject();
            const replyTextHyperlink = `<a href="https://mylink.com/${replyText}">${replyText}</a>`; 
            const replyBody = `Hello team, this has been addressed. Please see record ${replyTextHyperlink}.`;

            GmailApp.sendEmail("example@example.com", replySubject, "", {
                htmlBody: replyBody
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This replys in the thread:

```
function sendEmail() {
  const vs = getIdsAndSubjects();
  vs.forEach(function (r) {
    const messageId = r[0];
    const replyText = r[1];

    if (replyText && messageId) {
      const message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
      const replySubject = "Re: " + message.getSubject();
      const replyTextHyperlink = `<a href="https://mylink.com/${replyText}">${replyText}</a>`;
      const replyBody = `Hello team, this has been addressed. Please see record ${replyTextHyperlink}.`;

      message.getThread().reply(replyBody, { htmlBody: replyBody });
    }
  });
};
```

Using replyTo in the options object

```
function sendEmail() {
  const vs = getIdsAndSubjects();
  vs.forEach(function (r) {
    const messageId = r[0];
    const replyText = r[1];

    if (replyText && messageId) {
      const message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
      const replySubject = "Re: " + message.getSubject();
      const replyTextHyperlink = `<a href="https://mylink.com/${replyText}">${replyText}</a>`;
      const replyBody = `Hello team, this has been addressed. Please see record ${replyTextHyperlink}.`;

      message.getThread().reply(replyBody, { htmlBody: replyBody, replyTo: "" });
    }
  });
};
```

This is how  I got the data to test and I put it in the same format as getValues();

```
function getIdsAndSubjects() {
  const ts = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  let mA = [];
  ts.forEach(t => {
    t.getMessages().forEach(m => {
      mA.push([m.getId(),m.getSubject()])
    })
  });
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(mA))
  return mA;
}
```

Comment: The main issue is that I need to be able to reply in the thread to a specified address, not the original sender or recipients. I am starting to think Google Apps Script does not really have a good way to do this

Comment: Have you tried using replyTo in the options?

Comment: Yeah I treid replyTo and that seems to do it for me